# Override inline CSS using Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, css

I want to [override styles on a web page using Edge developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/javascript/overrides).

For regular files one can choose a source file, add to the Edge override, modify the local file and the override works as expected.

However, I wish to override the CSS, but all the CSS is inline (Sharepoint!). There are no stylesheets attached to any of the ~100 source files that this basic web page is composed from.

**Can I override the CSS with Edge-override?** Or with some other built-in method using Edge developer tools?

Any answer should not use require software install beyond Microsoft Edge itself, so no add-ons, and should work automatically when I access the relevant domain. The best answer would allow override even if dev tools are closed. Many thanks.

FWIW, I'm aware that this could be done using uBlock Origin (uBO), but that route is not available to me due to administrative policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the inline CSS with the `!important` keyword.
However, if the inline CSS is also marked as [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) then it's not possible to override it with external CSS!

Comment: Yes, but I need a solution which operates automatically when I view the page, the issue is not writing the overridden CSS it is, when using Edge, applying it when the page loads (without having to manually apply it). I'm in a locked down corporate environment, previously I used uBO for this but now all addons have been taken away.